# Randomize question text using Javascript in Qualtrics

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I am trying to setup a survey in Qualtrics and want to randomize each question in the following way. 
Every question asks the participant to make a choice, based on two variable parameters - Type of opponent (T) and Action (A). There are 6 types of opponent (T1,T2...T6) and 3 types of actions (A1,A2,A3). The actions have 6 replicates each (meaning there are 6 actions each of type A1,A2 and A3 A1[1..6],A2[1..6],A3[1..6]). There are 18 actions in total.

The question text will read

```
"You are playing against T[i] who has taken action Aj[k] "
i=1,2..6
j=1,2,3
k=1,2..6
```

I want to randomly assign the 6 questions in each action type to the 6 types of opponents - thereby generating 18 questions per subject.
How do i make the question text variable?
I have tried placing the following within the

`Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnReady(function(){})`

block as a first step to at least randomly generate one of the opponent types, but the text does not change at all.

I am a complete newbie to javascript, although I have other coding experience.

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnReady(function()
{
var opponent_types =["Red","Blue","Green","Yellow"];
    var selected_opponent_type = opponent_types[Math.floor(Math.random()*opponent_types.length)];
    this.QuestionText = selected_opponent_type;
})
```

I am sure this is a syntax issue, can someone please point me in the right direction to go about this? The document.write is disabled in the Qualtrics API.

Comment: kinda strange, I've never used Qualtrics, but from what I can see, you're code is fine, it's just the assignment part that's curious, I don't think the "this.QuestionText" is properly set up to update the values.   On their site https://www.qualtrics.com/support/survey-platform/survey-module/question-options/add-javascript/  - it looks like they recommend using JQuery to post update a value - so you'd have to know the thing you're trying to target, then ref it with Jquery and set it's html/value/text whatever you want to the selected_opponent_type

Comment: Thank you. I did indeed need to use jQuery(".QuestionText").